# how to get the value of a label placed on table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a number of cells in my tableview each containing different label values
when i tap on the cell I want that value of label in next view controller. how do I get that?

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as!
       MeetingsListTableViewCell
    
       if self.meeting.count > 0{
           let eachMeeting = self.meeting[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.meetingTimeLabel?.text = (eachMeeting["time"] as? String) ?? "No Time"
        cell.meetingDateLabel?.text = (eachMeeting["date"] as? String) ?? "No Date"
        cell.idLabel?.text = (eachMeeting["id"] as? String) ?? "NO ID"
       }
       return cell
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main4", bundle:Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MeetingDetailVC") as? MeetingDetailVC

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
   
}
```

i want that **idLabel** value to send in the next viewcontroller

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Get the data always from the data source array `meeting`, never from the cell, for example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let aMeeting = self.meeting[indexPath.row]
    let identifier = aMeeting["id"] as! String
    
    guard let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main4", bundle:Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MeetingDetailVC") as? MeetingDetailVC else { return } 
    vc.identifier = identifier
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The code assumes that there is a property identifier in `MeetingDetailVC`

---

Notes:

- For better readability you should name arrays in plural form (`meetings`).
- The check `self.meeting.count > 0` is pointless, `cellForRowAt` is not being called if the data source array is empty.
- It's highly recommended to use a custom struct as data source rather than an array of dictionaries. You will get rid of all those annoying type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Tapped cell can be accessed in *didSelectRowAt* function of *tableVeiw*. Extract tableView cell and cast int into your custom cell, after casting you can directly access value of lableId, add an optional property in *MeetingDetailVC* and pass value to it.